# Count the Number of match Word in Json

Tags: php, jquery, json, mysqli

how can i possibly count the word that matches a string... like that matched '201' in [image]

**THIS IS MY BACK END...**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");
function loadData()
{
    global $con;
    $listData="";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fGuests,mGuests FROM reserved");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $mf= array();
        $mf[]=$row['mGuests'].';'.$row['fGuests'];
        $data = array(
                    'mf'=>$mf
                    );
        $listData[]=$data;
    }
    return json_encode($listData);
}
echo loadData();
```

?>
**THIS IS MY AJAX...**

```
function x()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/try.php",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data:"",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $.each(data,function(i,item)
            {
                var m=item.match(/201/g).length;
                $("#roomList2").append(m);
            });
        }
    });
}
x();
```

IT ONLY OUTPUT 6...

IT SHOULD BE 8...

Comment: I only count 6 `tuper-201` in each row. Where are your other 2 coming from?

Comment: in array[2]... there r 2 201

Comment: Think I've fixed all the issues, you would've had an error when match returned null for array[1] which .length fails on. This would stop the .each loop.
I think you probably expected .each to return all of the sub items as one item rather than looping through them?

Comment: ok, sorry, rushed a bit first time:
heres fiddle of fixed version http://jsfiddle.net/qs7zt0qz/2/
full code in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are only reading through the first object in your array before appending (each loops through rather than returning all of the results concatenated). This is probably because you get an error when match returns null for the second element of the array (there is no 201 in that one). Need to add an if to check whether match returns anything. You also want to add these numbers together before appending them.

```
function x()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/try.php",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data:"",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var m = 0;
            $.each(data,function(i,item)
            {
                var matched = item.mf.match(/201/g);
                if(matched) {
                    m += matched.length;
                }
            });
            $("#roomList2").append(m);
        }
    });
}
x();
```

[jsfiddle of this working](http://jsfiddle.net/qs7zt0qz/2/)

Comment: it gives me Uncaught TypeError: item.match is not a function

Comment: yeah, I thought it might do that (surely your original code does as well)? Just copied that since I wasn't sure if your data returned was different. I'll fix this now (just have to change item to item.mf)

Comment: my json is this..

[{"mf":["tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201"]},{"mf":["4-000;5-000;6-000;1-000;2-000;3-000"]},{"mf":["zxc-301;asd-302;qwe-303;qwe-201;asd-201;zxc-203"]}]

Answer (score 1):

How about converting the `data` (object) into a string and then searching just once:

```
var strData = JSON.stringify( data );
var matched = strData.match(/201/g);
var m = matched ? matched.length : 0;
```

```js
var data = [
 {mf:["tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201"]},
 {mf:["tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201"]},
 {mf:["tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201;tuper-201"]},
 {mf:["4-000;5-000;6-000;1-000;2-000;3-000"]},
 {mf:["4-000;5-000;6-000;1-000;2-000;3-000"]}
];
var strData = JSON.stringify( data );
var matched = strData.match(/201/g);
var m = matched ? matched.length : 0;
alert( m );
```